# Google Oauth2 consent screen verification

Tags: google-oauth

We are setting up an "app" in Google Cloud Console for the sole purpose of single sign on - letting users sign into a WordPress site and a Moodle site using their Google accounts.

When setting up the "Oauth Consent Screen" - there is a "Submit for Verification" button which is disabled (grayed out). The verification Status is "not published".

The question: does it *need* to be verified? The documentation, such as there is, hints darkly at various limitations if it is not. Yet, there appears to be no path to get it verified.

It "works" in testing for allowing log in with Google account, but the organization has a large number of users. Are we going to hit limits if we go live with it?

We haven't added any scopes. Do we need to, just to get the ability to get it verified? It "works" in testing, *without* having added any scopes.

Any insight is welcome on how to get this app verified - or as whether we need to have it verified (maybe it can't be verified because it doesn't need to be?).

Comment: Have to got any lights?